# Remove unused styles in a Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I'd like to remove all the unused styls in order to shirnk the xap file, is there a tool for doing .xap size optimization?

Answer (score 1):

One way to reduce the XAP size is to have the System assemblies cached:
http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/04/06/silverlight-3-s-new-assembly-caching.aspx

StackOverflow's friebndly sponsor Telerik has a tool for reducing XAP size when you use their controls:
http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/10-06-10/telerik_assembly_minifier.aspx
I've tried it and it looks very OK, but I've not used it in production.

For finding unused styles, I've not found no better tools than the Find dialog (and an apprentice...)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small application for listing the unused styles in Silverlight. The source code and binary may be found here:

[Removing unused styles from Silverlight projects](http://www.kopf.com.br/kaplof/removing-unused-styles-from-silverlight-projects)

Cheers,

Bruno